# Show that $\sup\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{n} A_k\right) = \max(\sup{A_1}, \sup{A_2},\ldots,\sup{A_n})$

Tags: calculus

> Assume $A_1,\ldots,A_n$ are nonempty subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. Show that $$\displaystyle \sup\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{n} A_k\right) = \max(\sup{A_1}, \sup{A_2},\ldots,\sup{A_n}).$$

This intuitively makes sense. We know need to show that the right-hand side is the least upper bound for $\bigcup_{k=1}^{n} A_k$. It is an upper bound since the maximum of the supremums is greater than or equal any other element in $\bigcup_{k=1}^{n} A_k$. Now how do I show it is the least upper bound?

Comment: Can you do it for $n=1$ and for $n=1+1$?

Comment: An answer for two sets is here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217514/supremum-of-an-union-of-bounded-sets, it should not be too difficult to generalise that to $n$ sets.

Comment: Clearly, RHS is equal to $\sup A_k$ for some $k$. Now, any smaller number is not an upper bound for $A_k$, hence it is not an upper bound for $\bigcup A_k$.