# On the union of half-open intervals.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, proof-writing

Intuitively it is clear that the following equality is false:$$(a,b)=\bigcup_{k=1}^n (a_k,b_k],$$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, $a<b$ and $a_k,b_k\in\mathbb{R}$ with $a_k,b_k\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a_k< b_k$ for all $k\in\{1, \dots, n\}$.

I tried to give the following explanation: if it were true, after having increasingly rearranged the $a_k$, then necessary we have $$a_1=a\quad\text{and}\quad b_n=b.$$ And therefore $(a,b)=(a,b]$ and this is clearly absurd.

is it a good motivation or do you need a more formal proof?

**$\large\text{My attempt 2}$**

We have that $\sup(a,b)=b$, while $$\sup\left\{\cup_{k=1}^n (a_k,b_k]\right\}=\sup\{\sup(a_1,b_1], \dots, \sup (a_k,b_k]\}=\max\{b_1,\dots, b_k\}:=b_m,$$ then $b=b_m$ but $b\notin (a,b)$ while $b_m$ yes. Absurd.

> **Question.** It's correct?

Comment: Regarding a more formal prove, I would prove by induction that the upper bound of a finite union of half open intervals belongs to that union while this is not the case for an open interval.

Comment: Also note that the intervals $(a_k,b_k]$ may be disjoint, so their union may not be a half-open interval either.

Comment: In general you idea is good but you are making unwarranted assumptions.  we know $a_1 < a_2 < .... < a_n$ but not that $b_1 < b_2 < .... < b_n$.  Nor do we know that the intervals intersect (they wouldn't if there were a $a_{k+1} > b_k$) so we don't know the union is an single interval.  But we can show that $\sup \cup$ is $\sup b_k$ and that as there is a finite number of them that $\sup b_k = \max b_k = b_i$ for one of them and $(a,b)$ simply does not contain its $\sup$.  That's enough.  (Not sure I like you $\sup(\cup) = \max\{\sup A_1, \sup A_2,...\}$.  I'd like a more formal argument)

Comment: @fleablood Thanks! I drew from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217514/supremum-of-an-union-of-bounded-sets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall, that a set $A$ is open, if every $x\in A$ is an interior point, i.e. it has an open neighborhood which is contained in $A$.

We will show, that any finite union $\bigcup_{k=1}^n (a_k, b_k]$ contains a point which is no interior point.

Let $b_{\max}$ be $\max_k b_k$. Let $\epsilon>0$ and consider $(b_\max-\epsilon, b_\max +\epsilon)$. Since $b_\max$ is maximal, this open interval cannot be a subset of $\bigcup_{k=1}^n (a_k, b_k]$. As this holds for every $\epsilon$, the point $b_\max$ is not an interior point and so
the set $\bigcup_{k=1}^n (a_k, b_k]$ is not open.

**Important remark.**

Note that the argument hinges on the existence of the maximal point $b_k$. For ***infinite*** unions, it might not exist, and $\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty (a_k, b_k]$ can be open. For example $\bigcup_{k=2}^\infty (0, 1-\frac 1 k] = (0,1)$.

**Regarding your proof.** Your proof fails, if the intervals do not intersect.